# vaex create a unique dataframe using a dupplicated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, vaex

i'm using vaex library. input dataframe has dupplicate rows. i need to create new dataframe that can uniquly identify the group name and group hash like below output

```
input dataframe
group_name, group_hash
student, xxxx12313
student, xxxx12313
student, xxxx12313
Teacher, yyyyy2222
Teacher, yyyyy2222

output dataframe
group_name, group_hash
student, xxxx12313
Teacher, yyyyy2222
```